# mongodb aggregation $in with $type

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection:

```
{
  values: [null, null, 1, 2, 3, 4.6],
}
```

I want to receive a property which tells me if any of those values is a number.

I've tried:

```
{
    $project: {
        hasNumber: {
            $in: [{ $eq: [{ $type: '$$CURRENT' }, 'number'] }, '$values'],
        },
    },
}
```

but it doesn't work, is something like this possible with aggregations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        values: 1, hasNumber: {
            $gt: [{
                $size: {
                    $filter:
                    {
                        input: "$values",
                        as: "value",
                        cond: { $eq: [{ $type: '$$value' }, 'int'] }
                        // To check & include double as well, replace above cond with this :
                       //cond: { $or :[ {$eq: [{ $type: '$$value' }, 'int']} , {$eq: [{ $type: '$$value' }, 'double']}] }
                    }
                }
            }, 0]
        }
    }
}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14d9dd627ef78236ea77e3"),
    "values" : [ 
        null, 
        null, 
        1, 
        2, 
        3, 
        4.6
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14d9e4627ef78236ea785f"),
    "values" : [ 
        null, 
        null
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14decc627ef78236eb12d3"),
    "values" : [ 
        "1", 
        4.6
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14d9dd627ef78236ea77e3"),
        "values" : [
            null,
            null,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4.6
        ],
            "hasNumber" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14d9e4627ef78236ea785f"),
        "values" : [
            null,
            null
        ],
            "hasNumber" : false
}
/* 3 */ // If we're checking for double this hasNumber will be true
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e14decc627ef78236eb12d3"),
        "values" : [
            "1",
            4.6
        ],
            "hasNumber" : false
}
```

Comment: does it also works for `double`, could it be done using `number` instead of `int`?

Comment: could this be achieved with the $in operator though?

Comment: @DanielPérez : `$in` operator is mostly used to check a list of items - `Ex:-[1,2,3]` exists in an array field of an existing document `Ex :- values array [null,null,1,2,3,4.6]`, but usually inputs to `$in` will be from code, but using `$in` in aggregation pipeline seems not that much feasible, Do you want to pass a list of values and check in `values` array that any of passed input values type exists ?

Comment: I wanted something aking to javascript `array.find(el => typeof el === 'number')` method. I thought $in was the closest but it seems it's more like .includes

Comment: @DanielPérez : Yes it does `.includes`/`.filter` but not `.find` or `.some` :-) As far as I know mongo doesn't have something directly similar to `.find()` on array, So even here we're doing size check on filter..

Answer (score 2):

### Debugging your code...

```
$in: [{ $eq: [{ $type: '$$CURRENT' }, 'number'] }, '$values'],
```

You are checking if `false` is inside `$values`.

**Explanation:**

- ['$$CURRENT'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.CURRENT) returns raw document
- `{ $type: '$$CURRENT' }` returns `'object'`
- `$eq:['object', 'number']` will always return `false`
- `$in:[ 'false', '$values']` will be false

---

I've solved with `$convert` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      hasNumber: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $map: {
                  input: "$values",
                  in: {
                    $convert: {
                      input: "$$this",
                      to: "int",
                      onError: -999,
                      onNull: -999
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "$values"
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I see, 

    '$$CURRENT' returns raw document

...so, is there a way to use an iterator with the $in operator?